# DateTimePicker class change range

Tags: c#

I have a requirement to set a C# `DateTimePicker` control to change in range, I want it to display only **hour:min:second**, and I want the minimum value to be 10 seconds.

E.g.

```
if hour == 0 && min == 0
         then second should be limited to change within 10 ~ 59
      else second can change within 0 ~ 59
```

How can I do this?

Comment: For what? WPF? ASP.NET? WinForms? Have you tried anything so far that you could post (even if it's not currently working)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the event onValueChanged to the datePicker control. Here is the code which should work. This code is for win forms.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    if (dt.Seconds % 10 > 0)
    {            
        initialValue = true;
        dateTimePicker1.Value = dt.Seconds (-(dt.Seconds % 10));
    }

    _prevDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;

}


private DateTime _prevDate;
private bool initialValue = false;

private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(initialValue)
    {
        initialValue = false;
        return;
    }

    DateTime dt = dateTimePicker1.Value;
    TimeSpan diff = dt - _prevDate;

    if (diff.Ticks < 0) 
        dateTimePicker1.Value = _prevDate.AddSeconds(-10);
    else 
        dateTimePicker1.Value = _prevDate.AddSeconds(10);

    _prevDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;
}
```

You need to add this to the date picker:

```
    this.dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss";
    this.dateTimePicker1.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
    this.dateTimePicker1.ShowUpDown = true;
```

Comment: @Charlie you are welcome, good luck with your project or assignment ! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
I played a while, here is the solution:

namespace DataTimePicker1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime dt = dateTimePicker1.Value;

            if (dt.Hour == 0 && dt.Minute == 0 &&
                dt.Second < 10)
            {
                int inc = 10 - dt.Second;
                dateTimePicker1.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddSeconds(inc);
            }
        }
    }
}
```